# How to use on click Angular function to make page jump to div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have made an Angular function that leads to a link on click. My doubt is the I want the page to jump/scroll down when a cube is clicked in: https://codepen.io/Feners4/pen/KggAwg

I tried to link using an Id tag, but I wasn't successful.This is my Javascript:

```
directive('myClick', () => {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: (scope) => {
        scope.clicked = () => {
          console.log('pppp');
          window.location = "#/test.html";
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

The HTML of the cubes is the following:

```
<body ng-app="App">
  <div ng-click="clicked()" my-click class="wrap">
    <div class="cube" change-background colorcode=¨#f45642¨>
      <div class="front"><span>Resume</span></div>
      <div class="back"></div>
      <div class="top"></div>
      <div class="bottom"></div>
      <div class="left"></div>
      <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How can I use my function to achieve jumping the page to the bottom where I'm making a "second page" within the same one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see an `id` for `#/test.html` in your document.  You'll need to add the correct `id`.  Also, you'll want to use `window.location.hash`.

**For example:**

```
window.location.hash = "#snap1":
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular-scroll directive.

https://github.com/oblador/angular-scroll